# Store results on a json array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, records

i just want to know how to do that think, probably is easy but atm i can't find the way to do it.

I have this code:

```
$results = $resultado->getRecords();
foreach ( $results as $result ){
        // do something here
}
```

And i need to store every record in a json array. Why i need to do that? Becouse in the html page I show the last record, but I have a button which have to go back to the array of records, from last (100) to the first (1).
So, i think the best way to do it is to create a jSON array with an index of numbers, and then everytime I click the button, i acces to the correct number and show that record.

EDIT:
When i do that :

```
 $results = $resultado->getRecords();
 $json_data = json_encode($results);
```

my json_data returs this:

```
[{"_impl":{"_fields":{"Fecha Alta":["19\/03\/1994"],"Codigo":["test"],"Nombre":["test"],"Idioma":["test"],"Division":["test"],"Division 2":["test"],"Marca":["test"],"Empresa":["test"],"Stock":["test"],"Precio Unitario":["test"],"Urlpdf":["test.pdf"],"id":["4009"],"Vigente Desde":["test"]},"V5e7ec2d5":[],"_recordId":"4009","_modificationId":"2","_layout":{"_impl":{"_fm":{"V73ee434e":{"charset":"UTF-8","locale":"en","logLevel":3,"hostspec":"null","recordClass":"null","prevalidate":false,"database":"null","username":"null","password":"null"},"Vea4b3413":null,"V9a3dcbce":null},"_name":"null","_fields":{"Fecha Alta":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Fecha Alta","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Codigo":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Codigo","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"number","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Nombre":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Nombre","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Idioma":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Idioma","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Division":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Division","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Division 2":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Division 2","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Marca":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Marca","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Empresa":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Empresa","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Stock":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Stock","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Precio Unitario":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Precio Unitario","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"number","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Urlpdf":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Urlpdf","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"id":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"id","_autoEntered":true,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}},"Vigente Desde":{"_impl":{"_layout":null,"_name":"Vigente Desde","_autoEntered":false,"_global":false,"_maxRepeat":1,"_validationMask":0,"_validationRules":[],"_result":"text","_type":"normal","_valueList":null,"_styleType":null,"_maxCharacters":0}}},"_relatedSets":[],"_valueLists":[],"Vab234ad8":[],"_database":"null","_extended":false}},"_fm":{"V73ee434e":{"charset":"UTF-8","locale":"en","logLevel":3,"hostspec":"null","recordClass":"FileMaker_Record","prevalidate":false,"database":"null","username":"null","password":"null"},"Vea4b3413":null,"V9a3dcbce":null},"_relatedSets":[],"_parent":null}}]
```

Tbh i don't know why filemaker gives me that fields. I only need the first ones :

```
 {"Fecha Alta":["19\/03\/1994"],"Codigo":["test"],"Nombre":["test"],"Idioma":["test"],"Division":["test"],"Division 2":["test"],"Marca":["test"],"Empresa":["test"],"Stock":["test"],"Precio Unitario":["test"],"Urlpdf":["test.pdf"],"id":["4009"],"Vigente Desde":["test"]}
```

So, i only need what is in _fields {} .

How i should do it?

Thank you all guys!

Comment: you don't store in a "json array". you store in native PHP array, then encode that array into json. json is basically wrapping paper. you don't deal with the wrapping/unwrapping until you're done building the "present" you want wrapped.

Comment: You really need to tell us what $results equals.

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop, try this:

```
$results = $resultado->getRecords();
$json_data = json_encode($results);
```

Comment: That's nice, but how i can access to every one record? What i mean is..if i want to go to the 5 record, how can I access it? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexPerez show me the JSON produced, add it to your post please

Comment: @AlexPerez I am reading your post over and over I cannot understand what you wanna achieve, can you elaborate/clarify with examples

Comment: i want to save the values from the json encode result, which are the word "test" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$resultSet = array();
$results = $resultado->getRecords();
foreach ( $results as $result ){
    // Do your operation over $result 
    $resultSet[] = result;
}
$json_data = json_encode($resultSet);
```